# react stopPropagation not working at all

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use a component that is nested, however once I click on the component, I want to stop propagating the click event to parent elements that are behind the component.

For a simple example I did implement it like this:

```
public render() {
  return (
    <div data-id={i} onClick={this.showModal}>
  );
}
private showModal(e:any): void {
    //logic to show modal
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

However, the event and even the nativeEvent are NOT stopping at all, the method showModal is being called for every single nested instance.

Comment: Hard to say what might be wrong in your particular example, [but it seems to work fine generally](https://codesandbox.io/s/pklkknzr0).

Comment: This is the strange part it only seems to appear with typescript...